# How to replace part of a multi array variable with a different variable?

Tags: php, arrays

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
$array['aaa']['bbb']['ccc'] = "value";
$subarray = "['bbb']['ccc']";
echo $array['aaa']$subarray;       // these 2 echos should be the same
echo $array['aaa']['bbb']['ccc'];  // these 2 echos should be the same
```

It should display the same as `$array['aaa']['bbb']['ccc']` i.e., "value".

This doesnt work, of course. But is there some simple solution to this?
There could be some function and the `$subarray`value may be used as a parametr and/or as an array itself like: `$subarray = array('bbb','ccc');` I dont mind as long as it worsk.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below.

```
$subarray = "['bbb']['ccc']";
$temp = parse_str("\$array['aaa']".$subarray);
echo $temp;
```

OR To ignore single quotes -

```
$subarray = "[\'bbb\'][\'ccc\']";
$temp = parse_str("\$array[\'aaa\']".$subarray);
echo $temp;
```

Also you may refer - http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: More over you cant use dolar sign in double apostrophes  ("$ ") to make it look like a string

Comment: I tried: $string = 'echo $array[\'aaa\']' . $subarray . ';';
 parse_str($string); But it also didnt work..

Comment: Please remove echo from $string = 'echo $array[\'aaa\']' . $subarray . ';'; parse_str($string);  and try.

Comment: Try this - $string = '\$array[\'aaa\']' . $subarray ; echo parse_str($string);

Answer (score 0):

Just try using array chunk function http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Answer (score 0):

here is what actually works!!

```
$array['aaa']['bbb']['ccc'] = "value";
$subarray = "['bbb']['ccc']"; 
$string = 'echo $array[\'aaa\']' . $subarray . ';';
eval($string);
```